# Visualforce Page's outputText not updating when other outputPanels are next to it. Why?

Tags: visualforce, controller, rerender, rendering

I have the following controller variable {!selectedValue} that updates successfully on the page just fine when the markup next to it is commented out. However when I add the outputPanels back in, it only updates to the first value selected and stays with that value, despite changing the radio buttons.

Visualforce:

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" controller="CloneQuoteWithOrWithoutOpp" action="{!nullOutValues}">

<apex:outputText>Choose to either create/clone a new Opportunity or link to an existing Opportunity.</apex:outputText>
<apex:form>
    <apex:selectRadio id="slctRd" dir="ltr" required="true" layout="pageDirection" value="{!selectedValue}" immediate="true">
        <strong><font color="#FF0000"><apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!changeRadio}" rerender="valueId"/></font></strong>
        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Create New/Clone" itemValue="createNew"></apex:selectOption>
        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Link to Existing Opp" itemValue="linkToExisting"></apex:selectOption>
    </apex:selectRadio>

        <apex:outputText id="valueId" value="{!selectedValue}" />
        <!--Above text changes value when below is commented out-->
        <!--However if you uncomment below, then it updates once and stays with that value-->
        <!--
        <apex:outputPanel id="outputpanel1" rendered="{!IF(selectedValue == 'linkToExisting','true','false')}">
            <apex:outputLabel value="Opportunity to Link to"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!dummyQuoteForLookup.OpportunityId}" label="Opportunity to Link to"/>
        </apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:outputPanel id="outputpanel2" rendered="{!IF(selectedValue == 'createNew','true','false')}">
            <apex:outputLabel value="testing2"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!dummyQuoteForLookup.OpportunityId}" label="testing2"/>
        </apex:outputPanel>
        -->

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class CloneQuoteWithOrWithoutOpp {

    public Quote quoteId {get;set;}
    public Opportunity oppToLinkTo {get;set;}
    public Boolean createNew {get;set;}
    public Boolean linkToExisting {get;set;}
    public String selectedValue {get;set;}
    public Quote dummyQuoteForLookup {get;set;}

    public CloneQuoteWithOrWithoutOpp() {
        createNew = false;
        linkToExisting = false;
        dummyQuoteForLookup = [select id, OpportunityId from Quote order by CreatedDate limit 1];
        dummyQuoteForLookup.OpportunityId = null;
    }
    public PageReference changeRadio(){
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference nullOutValues(){
        dummyQuoteForLookup.OpportunityId = null;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the code like this way

Firstly, Remove `immediate=true` from `apex:selectRadio` which stops assigning controller attribute properly.

Secondly, Wrap those outputPanels (which are conditional) within a separate panel like here `myPanel` and try to render this `myPanel` from `actionSupport` `rerender` attribute.

Thirdly, instead of using `rendered="{!IF(selectedValue == 'linkToExisting','true','false')}"`, just use `rendered="{!selectedValue == 'linkToExisting'}"`

Fourthly, since you are using `required=true` for `apex:selectRadio`, better to wrap those inside `apex:actionRegion` which will help you to submit the page. I know you were trying to bypass this using `immediate=true`, which is now not needed.

Here is your changed code:

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" controller="CloneQuoteWithOrWithoutOpp" action="{!nullOutValues}">

<apex:outputText>Choose to either create/clone a new Opportunity or link to an existing Opportunity.</apex:outputText>
    <apex:form>
        <strong><font color="#FF0000">
        <apex:actionRegion>
        <apex:selectRadio id="slctRd" dir="ltr" required="true" layout="pageDirection" value="{!selectedValue}">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!changeRadio}" rerender="valueId,myPanel"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Create New/Clone" itemValue="createNew"></apex:selectOption>
            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Link to Existing Opp" itemValue="linkToExisting"></apex:selectOption>
        </apex:selectRadio>
        </apex:actionRegion>
        </font></strong>

            <apex:outputText id="valueId" value="{!selectedValue}" />
            <apex:outputPanel id="myPanel">
                <apex:actionRegion>
                <apex:outputPanel id="outputpanel1" rendered="{!selectedValue == 'linkToExisting'}">
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Opportunity to Link to"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!dummyQuoteForLookup.OpportunityId}" label="Opportunity to Link to"/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
                <apex:outputPanel id="outputpanel2" rendered="{!selectedValue == 'createNew'}">
                    <apex:outputLabel value="testing2"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!dummyQuoteForLookup.OpportunityId}" label="testing2"/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:actionRegion>
            </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Santanu! This worked out perfectly!!